# How to run forms in VB project on separate threads while still being able to communicate

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have been stuck with this issue for quite a long time. I have a VB.Net project, where I have several forms. However, if one of the forms freezes or crashes, the whole application crashes. I have not been able to find a way to be able to, when each form is displayed it is either in a separate process, or new thread and be able to retain the ability to communicate with other forms, as if it was on the main UI thread. I am in desperate need of finding a way to do this, but every time I create a new thread with a new form, the form immediately closes. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you should know.

While it is perfectly possible to have two separate forms run on two separate threads, it is a bad design (unless you really know what you're doing).  If you want to create a form on a separate thread, then you are also responsible for creating a message loop on that thread (otherwise your form will freeze).

Concretely, you do this with `Application.Run`

```
    _thread = New Thread(Sub()
                             Using frm As New SomeForm
                                 Application.Run(frm)
                             End Using
                         End Sub)
    _thread.Start()
```

Communication between forms on different threads is no different from communication between a normal thread and a form.  You could use a `ConcurrentQueue` of messages into which one thread writes instructions for the other thread to read, or simple shared variables.  You have to make sure that each thread only changes components or controls of the form it created.  To manipulate controls between threads, you have to use `Invoke`.